# Need help understanding how to version an iOS app

Tags: ios, version

In Xcode I have `Bundle Version` and `Bundle Version string, short`.  There is also a version in iTunes Connect.  Just trying to see what I should use for each one and which one iOS uses to determine the version of the app so that a newer version properly replaces and older version.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Long story short: you can just set both Bundle Version and Bundle Version string short to to the same value. You will need to increase them between submissions. The version in iTunes Connect is the version displayed to the user in the App Store and does not have to match the version strings in your Info.plist

Comment: Thanks for the info - is it possible to get a little more detail as to the intended purpose behind the two different values.  Or at least where I can find that information for myself.  Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Note that multiple version numbers are visible to the user. Apple does not require that they match. 'Bundle Short Version String' is the version that can be seen on the user's device in Settings > General > Storage > <the app>. You'll probably want to set this to match the version that is visible in the app store.

Answer (score 13):

Here's the [excellent post](http://www.blog.montgomerie.net/easy-iphone-application-versioning-with-agvtool) on how to do the versioning easy way. My general approach is tou use x.y.z where 'x' is gets increased on major releases, 'y' is increased for versions introducing new functionality and 'z' is used for bug-fixes releases. Examples: 1.0.0, 1.0.4, 3.2.1 etc...
The relation between Bundle Version and iTunes connect is simple: whatever you use for your version in the Xcode, is also used in iTunes, so the user of your app can identify you app version easily - you just have to be consistent. Later you can introduce more granularity, e.g. build numbers.

**EDIT:**
<strike>Important addition: your app can get rejected if you're inconsistent with numbering. More details [here](http://www.apprejected.com/?p=19).</strike> dead link, however it is still true that because of inconsistent versioning app can get rejected.

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian : Yes it does.

Comment: But the second link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
NSLog(@"version is%@",version);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  When you post an answer like this to a question that was asked more than a year ago that has accepted answers, your answer needs to cover new material (which yours does), and it needs to be explained so it is clear why your answer is better than others.  A single line of code probably isn't sufficient.  Can you provide an explanation?